# Error even after enabling --shell-escape in TeXworks and installing gnuplots 5.4, when using gnuplot {4*x**2 - 5}

Tags: pgfplots, gnuplot, texworks, shell-escape

On my troubleshooting of the code got from page 42/571 of the pgfplots package:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot+ [id=parable,domain=-5:5,] gnuplot {4*x**2 - 5} node [pin=180:{$4x^2-5$}]{};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I followed the steps as below:

1. Installed successfully the gnuplot version 5.4 patchlevel 1
2. On my TeXworks window went to Edit->Preference shown below:
   [image]
3. The TeXwrks preference window pops up. I hit on typesetting tab. In Processing tool section I hit on pdfLaTeX, as below:
   [image]
4. Then Hit on Edit... box. To get the tool configuration window as below:
   [image]
5. I hit on + box and type --shell-escape, as below:

[image]

6. Using up-arrow I move the --shell-escape up on top of $fullname and hit ok:

[image]

7. Then Run the code using pdfLaTeX getting the following error:

> ! Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, the gnuplot-result file 'f2_addplot_pgfplots_p
> p42.parable.table' could not be found. Maybe you need to enable the shell-escap
> e feature? For pdflatex, this is '>> pdflatex -shell-escape'. You can also invo
> ke '>> gnuplot .gnuplot' manually on the respective gnuplot file..
> See the pgfplots package documentation for explanation.
> Type  H   for immediate help.
> ...
> l.8 ...t {4*x**2 - 5} node [pin=180:{$4x^2-5$}]{};

Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Have you installed gnuplot at your PATH?

Comment: Yes Installed successfully the gnuplot version 5.4 patchlevel 1

Comment: I mean like in the picture (https://www.fnu.uni-hamburg.de/16917560/addpath-54692c0304a8aea26b721ec6033dbfb368a85f8f.jpg)?

Comment: I did not check the box you highlighted. I try and let you know.

Comment: Yes it works by your solution. Would you please put youe answer below and I accept it as the correct answer?

Comment: Nice to hear. Now you can get started

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to combine `gnuplot` and `LaTeX`, you have to 1. install `gnuplot` at your `PATH` and 2. to run pdflatex with shell-escape, i.e. `pdflatex -shell-escape ...` or `pdflatex --enable-write18 ...`

The first point can be checked typing `gnuplot --version` and `PATH` in your cmd, which should return `gnuplot ... patchlevel ...` and a list of the elements in your `PATH` (something like `C:\Program Files\gnuplot\bin`).
Therefore, it is the easiest way to enable the shown option during the installation of `gnuplot`.

[image]